# How to stream video/images from python app to a remote ReactJS webpage

Tags: python, reactjs, video-streaming

I have been searching for this solution but not sure of the direction to go.
I have a python app using OpenCV to stream realtime video cameras (CCTV). So when I sit on the pc itself where the app is running I can open the cameras in the app and see the videos playing (using cv2.imshow).

However I now am looking to view the videos from a ReactJS webpage on a remote machine. So I need to connect to the python app that is always running on the remote pc and stream the video to the ReactJS webpage (while ensuring the video is compressed and secure).

This is the struggle.

There are tutorials on Sockets, Websockets, Flask, Mjpeg streamers. However as a noob to this portion I am not sure the correct route to take.

I am looking for assistance (not necessarily the code) as to how to what to search for, what technology is used to achieve this. So would appreciate if someone can guide me on the correct initial way forward.

Much appreciated.

Comment: you need something like this : https://github.com/prabhakar-sivanesan/OpenCV-rtsp-server, A RTSP server that serves the video to your web client.

Comment: OpenCV is not for video streaming. it's for computer vision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To establish the flask/opencv connection you do something like the following. In your flask you setup a function:

```
def webcam():
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while True:
        success, frame = camera.read()
        if success:
    
            ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            frame = buffer.tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')
        else:
            camera.release()
```

And you setup an API endpoint

```
@app.route('/webcam')
def webcam_display():
    return Response(webcam(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; 
                    boundary=frame')
```

And in your frontend to display the stream, you just call the api endpoint in the image source.

```
    <img src={url} alt="webcam" />
```

If there are multiple cameras you could maybe set up multiple endpoints and then via frontend connect to whatever endpoint you need via state at the time.

Hope this helps!